# SVN: Difference betweeen Replace with > Latest from repository and Team > Revert

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I would like to know the difference between the `Replace With > Latest from Repository` and `Team > Revert`. I use both of them but never know the difference, they do the same function?

My environment is Windows 10, Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 with Subclipse 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *Replace With > Latest from Repository* you also get commits that have been made by others in the meantime (since your last update).

In contrast, *Team > Revert...* does not require a connection to the server and only reverts your own changes.